# How to restart graphical interface in frozen PC running Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gnome, gui, reboot

I have a computer running Ubuntu 22.04. For some reason, the screen and keyboard are frozen, but I still can SSH into that computer, and use it normally in this way. However, I need the GUI for one app that I have to use. How can I restart the GUI without restarting the PC? I have already tried:

1. <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1,...,F7</kbd>, which normally brings you to the no-GUI interface. What happened is that the PC went into one of these screens but now it is frozen there, I cannot login from there nor go to one of the other screens nor go back to the GUI.
2. `killall -3 gnome-shell`, nothing changed.
3. `sudo systemctl restart gdm`, nothing changes.
4. Looking for processes sucking up all the resources, using `htop`. Did not find anything strange.

Note: After running `sudo systemctl restart systemd-logind` in an SSH session, now the PC is responsive again, meaning that I can switch using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1,...,F7</kbd> and login with the text interface.

Comment: You probably want `sudo systemctl restart gdm3` given the service is gdm3, not gdm.